# How to give an ip to guest os on esxi

Tags: networking, vmware, virtualization, esxi, dedicated-server

I am very new at networking, i just rent a dell server and installed ( hostig company installed ) an esxi.

I create a guest os but i cant give the ip adress to this guest. There is no panel or someting.
I installed vSphere client.

Can you guys help me ? What should i do now?

I know some of the basic networking terms but i cant handle this by myself.

here is a screenshot
http://s18.postimage.org/dg5us5thz/Capture.png

Answer (score 1):

What is your Guest OS type?

Setting up an IP address in the **console** of a VM is just like assigning an IP on a physical system. Ensure you have the network your trying to place the VM on set on the physical adapter You have 1 physical adapter on that switch on the 176.53.xxx network that is supporting the network your ESX(i) system is on and your VMs in the current set up.

Are there other physical adapters that aren't attached to vSwitches?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please check whether your Dell Server hardware is under the system requirement to install ESXi.

Here's the link to check the minimum hardware requirements:-

kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003661

To configure the network, please have a look at the EXi 4.1 setup guide, please refer to page 48, 51 and 52:-
http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp_41_esxi_i_vc_setup_guide.pdf

MW@DELL

Dell | Social Outreach Services - Enterprise

Get Support on Twitter @DellCaresPro

Comment: Thanks. My server is Dell r210. at the document it just teach how can we give an ip adress to main server. but it already given on my situation.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that your hosting provider doesn't have dhcp running or your guest would likely be picking up an address automatically.

did your hosting provider give you an address/address range to use for your guests?

you'll likely have to statically configure the ip address once you've completed the guest operating system install.

this is not an esxi/vmware configuration setting.

on windows, this would be done in control panel. in linux, you can either do it via command line or through the gui.

what guest operating system are you using? if linux, which distribution? are you using the gui or are you console-only?